# Oozie workflow.xml error

Tags: xml, hadoop, oozie

I am really new to the hadoop eco system and I have been trying to co ordinate and execute a basic pig job via Oozie.

I get the following error when I try to validate my workflow.xml file.

**Error:**

> Invalid app definition, org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 32;
>   columnNumber: 16; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'workflow-app' cannot
>   have character [children], because the type's content type is
>   element-only.

Here is my workflow.xml file for your reference.

```
  1 <workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="log-wf">
  2 <start to="pig-node"/>
  3  
  4 <action name="pig-node">
  5     <pig>
  6         <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
  7         <name-node>${namenode}</name-node>
  8         <prepare>
  9             <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${appRoot}/pigOutput"/>
 10         </prepare>
 11         <configuration>
 12             <property>
 13                 <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
 14                 <value>${queueName}</value>
 15             </property>
 16             <property>
 17                 <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
 18                 <value>true</value>
 19             </property>
 20         </configuration>
 21         <script>script.pig</script>
 22         <param>piginput=/user/${appRoot}/clean.log</param>
 23         <param>pigoutput=/user/${appRoot}/pigOutput</param>
 24     </pig>
 25     <ok to="end"/>
 26     <error to="fail"/>
 27 </action>
 28 
 29 
 30 
 31  <end name="end"/>
 32 </workflow-app>
```

I do not understand which element inside the workflow tag is causing the error since there is no 16th column on the 32nd line. Do you guys have any suggestions on this?

Comment: Does the same happen when no pretty formatting present (like, blank lines, indents with tabs)?

Comment: I removed all the pretty formatting and it worked. Thanks a lot! Would you know why formatting causes an error? Is it something common when dealing with XML files?

Comment: It is common to xml files but it's not formatting by itself, just some symbols that are not parsed as whitespace. Review the original workflow file to see what's wrong with it. But in general you can keep your xml files formatted, it's just a matter of having a decent editor :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to xml files but it's not formatting by itself, just some symbols that are not parsed as whitespace. Review the original workflow file to see what's wrong with it. But in general you can keep your xml files formatted, it's just a matter of having a decent editor :) . –  @patrungel

Thanks for your response.